# Rewrite rule for targeting http only (no https)

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, https, cpanel

A website that I manage was currently turned via cpanel to redirect at https. Unfortunately a single site/folder/program works only in http and not in https (idk why).
Is there any rewrite rule that will force this site to load in http only?

The whole thing is made like this:

- `https://example.com`  --> HTTPS (ok and desired to be in https)
- `http://example.com/NastyWebApp` --> HTTP (doesn't work in https)

What I need, is to force the NastyWebApp to load in http only.

Comment: Modern browsers will reliably block all attempts to make a unencrypted connection from a page loaded via an encrypted connection, likewise they will block all attempts to dŕedirect an encrypted connection to an unencypted one. For very good reasons. Instead I sugegst you invest time into understanding and fixing the issue with that "single site/folder/page" does not work correctly. Always fix the cause, not the symptom.

Comment: "works only in http and not in https (idk why)" - What do you mean exactly that it does not work in HTTPS? What response do you get?

Comment: Page was showing blank, now after the trick i did, when I put https in front of url, it shows results like ftp (they only run a index.php file) but doesn't go further. It is just a form where you fill a password-like number and then you advance further in the app. With http only, it works as expected.

Comment: @arkascha, as I said to another comment, I totally agree. However it is not up to me for this, unfortunately. I ve said my arguments, and now it is up to someone else to make the decisions to fix the problem. Anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not the ideal solution, but a solution that will do the job, via Javascript:

```
<HTML><HEAD><title>Nasty Web App</title></HEAD>
<body><SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">(window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com/nastywebapp.php"));
```

Comment: Have you tried this yourself? I'd say that this won't work. You cannot trick a modern browser into loading an http page from within an https page.

Comment: Yes and it works. I wouldn't put it as an answer otherwise. Running with a modern browser as well. I do not have access to the app that it was made from someone else. What you say is correct (fix the cause, not the symptom) but I am not able to reach out to the problem. Sometimes bureaucracy pushes you to fix the symptom unfortunately.